# How should I deal with the Facebook app privacy policy URL in developers page?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-login, privacy-policy

I'm trying to import fb-login function and there are some features which need to be inspected by facebook such as job status, education, etc.
And they're saying that they requires privacy policy URL. So, I made a facebook page, which I will use as a landing page for my app, and wrote down the Privacy Policy to the Note.

After that, I copied the note's url and pasted it to the Privacy Policy URL box. I tried to save and proceed, but than error message comes up,

> Facebook URL: Facebook URL cannot be crawled

So, my question is this: Is it unavailable to use facebook page to submit the privacy policy URL? This is my first time importing fb-login, so I just don't know what should I do and what shouldn't I do.

Comment: It need to be a link to your server. It can't be a Note on Facebooks server.

Answer (score 153):

**This should work** ( *Kind of a trick to fool FB* ;) )

1. Create a free privacy policy [here](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/).
2. Upload your privacy policy (the one you just created) to your google drive account.
3. Select the uploaded privacy policy file and click on ***Get Shareable link***. Copy and paste the generated link into your facebook app's ***Privacy Policy URL*** input box and click on save changes.

Thanks ☺️

Comment: still showing this "Your app must be available in every public store in order take your app Live. Make sure the ID 'package_name' is valid or remove the platform until the app is available."

Comment: they even offer to host the policy themselves by providing a link

Comment: Step 1. ok 

Step 2: I save privacy policy in a abc.html and abc.txt 

step 3: I upload both of them to google driver, get shareable link. But they do not work. What's wrong ?

Comment: @MrSpecial You only need `.html` file and paste the generated link into Facebook privacy policy url input box.

Comment: as I said, i used both .html, .txt as well. please take a look - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_paBiGtvHj56RqBy-V0KJABAopxmvR7a/view
what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe it used to be "free", but far from it now. Even for a VERY basic privacy policy you'll probably pay $35.

Comment: GDPR wording +$24. As a Bussiness +$14.

Comment: This is not free at all! On the contrary, this is a severely expensive service!

Comment: It's free if you don't but the extra options. And they even host it for free, so you can just copy and paste the URL they give you into Facebook.

Answer (score 9):

This is likely the problem.

> After that, I copied the note's url and pasted it to the Privacy
>   Policy URL box. I tried to save and proceed, but than error message
>   comes up, 'Facebook URL: Facebook URL cannot be crawled'

Instead of using a Facebook note, you're likely required to host that privacy policy yourself publicly. Given that Facebook can be a silo and hide pages whenever they like from the public web, you'd be well advised to move it to a site of yours.

This also seems to be Facebook's requirement:

> Provide a publicly available and easily accessible privacy policy that
>   explains what data you are collecting and how you will use that data.
>
> You may use Account Information in accordance with your privacy policy
>   and other Facebook policies. All other data may only be used outside
>   your app after you have obtained explicit user consent.
>
> Include your privacy policy URL in the App Dashboard.
>
> Link to your privacy policy in any app marketplace that allows you to.
>
> Comply with your privacy policy.

**How can you do that?**
There are a few options:

- host on your own site
- host on sites that allow to create public and persistent pages (just a thought, github?)
- use a dedicated tool for [privacy policy creation **and hosting** like iubenda](http://www.iubenda.com)

Hope this helps (p.s. I work for iubenda)

Answer (score 8):

Facebook has provided a link to test your URL which will show you that your URL is as per their standard or not.

Test your URL here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Answer (score 4):

Working
go to this link https://developers.facebook.com/apps
then click Basic tab setting

scroll down till you see  +add platform tab and click it

remove all allowed platform link android web....NB makes sure you have the details saved somewhere else ..like on notepad

then go to top and switch the mode from off to live.
your app will be live 
then go down again to add platform and add your plaform like android or web

Answer (score 2):

The URL to your Privacy Policy must be **public and accessible**. That's both a requirement from Facebook and law (see California Business Code and CalOPPA in the US). Here's [Facebook Developer Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

[image]

If you received the `Facebook URL: Facebook URL cannot be crawled` try to also not block bots access to the Privacy Policy page, i.e. Facebook Link Preview could crawl it or Google bot.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a free solution, I used https://www.termsfeed.com/privacy-policy-generator/ and it was validated in the Meta API in less than 2 minutes.

This site will offer a paid professional solution, but the free one worked like a charm.

Don't worry about hosting. the site gives you a hosted url

Answer (score 0):

Some of the previous suggestions are not for free as for now. One of the free options I found:

https://www.iubenda.com/en/start-generating

Be sure to select Facebook app, NOT Mobile app, and click "Start Generating"

Answer (score -1):

Go to Dashboard, Click on the Application
Go to Settings --> Basic at Sidebar
Remove apps if there is any under Add platform
Add policy URL and Turn the status to LIVE

and then you can add apps of your choice for live apps